# How do I display resultset from async await

Tags: json, rest, express, async-await, httpresponse

I am trying to display the resultset of this query as a json list. However only the top record is being displayed. How do I return multiple records from async await.

[image]

This is the output I want
[image]

This is the output I get
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the first item from the array, don't do it if you want the full result set.

```js
const arr = [{a:'a'}]
const [a] = arr

console.log(a)
```

Comment: I've added some some screenshots to give a better idea of the output I am looking for. I believe my syntax  on the lines -" const[schedules] = await query(text,[operatorId]); 
return schedules "  is what is giving the incorrect output. Could you tell me how I can fix it to display the result as a json list like the one seen in picture 2 of the question description.

Comment: yes, change `const [schedules] = await` to `return await`